# Get the Difference of two tables along with duplicate records and store in 3rd table in Azure SQL DB

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, duplicates, azure-sql-database

We are using Azure SQL database. We have 2 similar tables which contain duplicate rows, I want to get the difference between these tables and store it in a third table and duplicate rows should also be loaded.

If I am using `EXCEPT` it only loads unique rows.

How can I evaluate this with a SQL command? I don't want to use a stored procedure to get the result.

Here is a sample of the problem

Input tables:

TABLE A

```
AppName Creation Time   Completion Time Status
--------------------------------------------------
App A   8/8/2020        8/9/2020        Completed
App A   8/8/2020        8/9/2020        Completed
App B   8/8/2020        8/9/2020        Completed
App B   8/8/2020        8/9/2020        Completed
App C   8/9/2020        8/10/2020       Completed
App C   8/9/2020        8/10/2020       Completed
App D   8/10/2020       8/11/2020       Completed
```

TABLE B

```
AppName Creation Time   Completion Time  Status
--------------------------------------------------
App B   8/8/2020        8/9/2020         Completed
App B   8/8/2020        8/9/2020         Completed
App C   8/9/2020        8/10/2020        Completed
App C   8/9/2020        8/10/2020        Completed
App D   8/10/2020       8/11/2020        Completed
App E   8/10/2020       8/11/2020        Completed
App E   8/10/2020       8/11/2020        Completed
App F   8/11/2020       8/12/2020        Completed
App F   8/11/2020       8/12/2020        Completed
```

Expected output:

Table B minus A:

```
AppName Creation Time   Completion Time   Status
---------------------------------------------------
App E   8/10/2020       8/11/2020         Completed
App E   8/10/2020       8/11/2020         Completed
App F   8/11/2020       8/12/2020         Completed
App F   8/11/2020       8/12/2020         Completed
```

Table A minus B:

```
AppName Creation Time   Completion Time   Status
---------------------------------------------------
App A   8/8/2020        8/9/2020          Completed
App A   8/8/2020        8/9/2020          Completed
```

Comment: Your *time*-named columns appear to be dates, *not* times?

Answer (score 1):

CTE function is supported on Azure sql, use this function and exclude the matching records.

```
;with cte_excl
As (
Select distinct a.appname
From tableA a
Join tableB b on a.appname = b.appname
)

Select a.*
From (   select * from tableA union all select * from tableB )a
Left Join excl e on a.appname=e.appname
Where e.appname is null
```

Comment: Hi

Thanks, it works as well...

Answer (score 1):

I think you're after the following - get rows that don't exist comparing A to B and B to A, then union the results:

```
select * 
from ta 
where not exists (
    select * from tb 
        where tb.appname=ta.appname 
            and tb.creation=ta.creation 
            and tb.completion=ta.completion 
            and tb.status=ta.status
    )
union all
select * 
from tb 
where not exists (
    select * from ta 
        where ta.appname=tb.appname 
            and ta.creation=tb.creation 
            and ta.completion=tb.completion 
            and ta.status=tb.status
    )
```

[See Demo DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=f1cc853cffa979d1fd7b51aceb155ea7)

Comment: I am interested in TB-TA, 
However Not Exists or Not In also returns Unique rows

I used below statement

SELECT * FROM TB where not exists (select * from TA where TA.AppId = TB.AppId)

Comment: Sorry, It worked fine, and it works with "Not In" as well...
This is the statement I used...

SELECT * FROM TA where AppId not in (select JobId from TB)

Thanks

Comment: @SaurabhMehta Avoid `NOT IN` because of issues with nullable columns, better use `NOT EXISTS`

Answer (score 0):

I used the Data and table scripts provided by above Stu's post.  The above all answers are working fine and providing you solutions.

I only considered the Appname to find the differences here.

```
create table ta (appname varchar(10), creation date, completion date, status varchar(10));
 create table tb (appname varchar(10), creation date, completion date, status varchar(10));

 insert into ta values
  ('App A', '8/08/2020', '8/09/2020', 'Completed'),
  ('App A', '8/08/2020', '8/09/2020', 'Completed'),
  ('App B', '8/08/2020', '8/09/2020', 'Completed'),
  ('App B', '8/08/2020', '8/09/2020', 'Completed'),
  ('App C', '8/09/2020', '8/10/2020', 'Completed'),
  ('App C', '8/09/2020', '8/10/2020', 'Completed'),
  ('App D', '8/10/2020', '8/11/2020', 'Completed');

 insert into tb values
   ('App B','8/08/2020','8/09/2020','Completed'),
   ('App B','8/08/2020','8/09/2020','Completed'),
   ('App C','8/09/2020','8/10/2020','Completed'),
   ('App C','8/09/2020','8/10/2020','Completed'),
   ('App D','8/10/2020','8/11/2020','Completed'),
   ('App E','8/10/2020','8/11/2020','Completed'),
   ('App E','8/10/2020','8/11/2020','Completed'),
   ('App F','8/11/2020','8/12/2020','Completed'),
   ('App F','8/11/2020','8/12/2020','Completed');
```

Answer:

```
    Select * from ta 
    where ta.appname not in  ( Select appname from tb)
    UNION ALL
    Select * from tb 
    where tb.appname not in  ( Select appname from ta)
```

If you need results separately, remove the UNION ALL.
[image: Result]

Comment: @SaurabhMehta Please have a look. Above answers also provide the desired outputs.  I also added one thinking the App name column can be used to get the result.